# Flask send_file does not search for file in intended path

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask, send_file
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/download")
def download():
    return send_file("/home/user/MAIN/somefile.zip")
app.run()
```

I get this error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory '/home/user/MAIN/home/user/MAIN/somefile.zip'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `send_file` is using a relative URL - you just need to remove the `home/user/MAIN/` bit from the file path, then it should work